# How to use ActiveX DLL in Visual Foxpro 6?

Tags: dll, com, activex, visual-foxpro

I have an ActiveX COM DLL developed in VB6. How can I use it in Visual Foxpro 6?

Please explain with Visual Foxpro 6 code.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
myObject = CREATEOBJECT("Project.Class")
myObject.RunMethod()
```